# Serial Line specific font rendering

Tags: microsoft-office, fonts

I have two lines in first page of word document with just two lines as follows

Line 1- Name in Native language (Marathi)- Arjun wide font
Line 2 - Name in English - Times New roman font

I have 100 such pages

Now I want to make first line font to Arjun wide font and second line font to Times New Roman by default in all 100 pages. How to change like this without manually changing each line font.